# как сделать адаптивный, динамический collectionview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Всем здравствуйте, как только не настраивал, все никак. Подскажите как настроить collection view чтобы он был динамическим
Нужно так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как выглядит мой view
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо
Вот констрейнты collectionview
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот констрейнты stackview
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Надо видеть ваш код. Но вообще - скорее всего у вас не задано свойство height ячейки

Comment: А каким образом я задам констрейнт collection view cell?

Comment: Это зависит от того, как именно вы отрисовываете collectionview, это можно сделать несколькими способами. Но вообще это довольно просто.

Comment: Можете пожалуйста привести примеры

Comment: Вот простой пример: https://medium.com/yay-its-erica/creating-a-collection-view-swift-3-77da2898bb7c

Comment: Если не подходит, выложите ваш пример, я покажу что изменить